# Python ImportLib 'No Module Named'

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm trying to use a variable as a module to import from in Python.

Using ImportLib I have been successfully able to find the test...

```
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + '\\tests')
tool_name = selected_tool.split(".")[0]
selected_module = importlib.import_module("script1")
print(selected_module)
```

... and by printing the select_module I can see that it succesfully finds the script:

```
<module 'script1' from 'C:\\Users\\.....">
```

However, when I try to use this variable in the code to import a module from it:

```
from selected_module import run
run(1337)
```

The program quits with the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'selected_module'
```

I have tried to add a **init**.py file to the main directory and the /test directory where the scripts are, but to no avail. I'm sure it's just something stupidly small I'm missing - does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import statements are not sensitive to variables! Their content are treated as literals

An example:

```
urllib = "foo"
from urllib import parse   # loads "urllib.parse", not "foo.parse"
print(parse)
```

Note that `from my_module import my_func` will simply bind `my_module.my_func` to the local name `my_func`. If you have already imported the module via `importlib.import_module`, you can just do this yourself:

```
# ... your code here
run = selected_module.run  # bind module function to local name
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for the help! It worked perfectly when I instead of having the from " import ", just did selected_module.run.